# Qt Creator app won't build after updating MacOS to 1.015.4 and Xcode to 11.4, how to solve?

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qml, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator to create applications for Android and iOS. I recently migrated to MacOS 10.15.4 Catalina, and upgraded Xcode to 11.4, and after that the project stopped starting.

It produces the following error: [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 64

I can provide a full error code if necessary.

Perhaps the error is due to the transition to the new version of Xcode. Maybe you need to change something in the settings?

I'm counting on you :)

Full error code:

```
14:31:44: Running steps for project iValentina...
14:31:44: Starting: "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/bin/qmake" /Users/rz/Documents/ivalentina/iValentina.pro -spec macx-ios-clang CONFIG+=iphonesimulator CONFIG+=simulator CONFIG+=qml_debug
14:31:47: The process "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/bin/qmake" exited normally.
14:31:47: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -f /Users/rz/Desktop/FOLDERS/iOS_Simulator_Build/Makefile qmake_all
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/devices.py", line 78, in <module>
if is_suitable_runtime(runtimes, runtime_name, args.platform, args.minimum_deployment_target):
  File "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/devices.py", line 53, in is_suitable_runtime
and "unavailable" not in runtime["availability"] \
KeyError: 'availability'
make: Nothing to be done for `qmake_all'.
14:31:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
14:31:48: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/devices.py", line 78, in <module>
if is_suitable_runtime(runtimes, runtime_name, args.platform, args.minimum_deployment_target):
  File "/Users/rz/Qt/5.12.1/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/devices.py", line 53, in is_suitable_runtime
and "unavailable" not in runtime["availability"] \
KeyError: 'availability'
xcodebuild build  -project iValentina.xcodeproj -scheme iValentina   -configuration Debug  -destination "id=" -destination-timeout 1  ENABLE_ONLY_ACTIVE_RESOURCES=NO 
xcodebuild: error: missing value for key 'id' of option 'Destination'

Usage: xcodebuild [-project <projectname>] [[-target <targetname>]...|-alltargets] [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings [-json]] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
   xcodebuild [-project <projectname>] -scheme <schemeName> [-destination <destinationspecifier>]... [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings [-json]] [-showdestinations] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
   xcodebuild -workspace <workspacename> -scheme <schemeName> [-destination <destinationspecifier>]... [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings] [-showdestinations] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
   xcodebuild -version [-sdk [<sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>] [-json] [<infoitem>] ]
   xcodebuild -list [[-project <projectname>]|[-workspace <workspacename>]] [-json]
   xcodebuild -showsdks [-json]
   xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <xcarchivepath> [-exportPath <destinationpath>] -exportOptionsPlist <plistpath>
   xcodebuild -exportNotarizedApp -archivePath <xcarchivepath> -exportPath <destinationpath>
   xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <path> -project <projectname> [-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>...[-includeScreenshots]]
   xcodebuild -importLocalizations -localizationPath <path> -project <projectname>
   xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies [-project <projectname>|-workspace <workspacename>] -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath <path>
   xcodebuild -create-xcframework [-help] [-framework <path>] [-library <path> [-headers <path>]] -output <path>

Options:
-usage                                                   print brief usage
-help                                                    print complete usage
-verbose                                                 provide additional status output
-license                                                 show the Xcode and SDK license agreements
-checkFirstLaunchStatus                                  Check if any First Launch tasks need to be performed
-runFirstLaunch                                          install packages and agree to the license
-project NAME                                            build the project NAME
-target NAME                                             build the target NAME
-alltargets                                              build all targets
-workspace NAME                                          build the workspace NAME
-scheme NAME                                             build the scheme NAME
-configuration NAME                                      use the build configuration NAME for building each target
-xcconfig PATH                                           apply the build settings defined in the file at PATH as overrides
-arch ARCH                                               build each target for the architecture ARCH; this will override architectures defined in the project
-sdk SDK                                                 use SDK as the name or path of the base SDK when building the project
-toolchain NAME                                          use the toolchain with identifier or name NAME
-destination DESTINATIONSPECIFIER                        use the destination described by DESTINATIONSPECIFIER (a comma-separated set of key=value pairs describing the destination to use)
-destination-timeout TIMEOUT                             wait for TIMEOUT seconds while searching for the destination device
-parallelizeTargets                                      build independent targets in parallel
-jobs NUMBER                                             specify the maximum number of concurrent build operations
-maximum-concurrent-test-device-destinations NUMBER      the maximum number of device destinations to test on concurrently
-maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations NUMBER   the maximum number of simulator destinations to test on concurrently
-parallel-testing-enabled YES|NO                         overrides the per-target setting in the scheme
-parallel-testing-worker-count NUMBER                    the exact number of test runners that will be spawned during parallel testing
-maximum-parallel-testing-workers NUMBER                 the maximum number of test runners that will be spawned during parallel testing
-dry-run                                                 do everything except actually running the commands
-quiet                                                   do not print any output except for warnings and errors
-hideShellScriptEnvironment                              don't show shell script environment variables in build log
-showsdks                                                display a compact list of the installed SDKs
-showdestinations                                        display a list of destinations
-showTestPlans                                           display a list of test plans
-showBuildSettings                                       display a list of build settings and values
-showBuildSettingsForIndex                               display build settings for the index service
-list                                                    lists the targets and configurations in a project, or the schemes in a workspace
-find-executable NAME                                    display the full path to executable NAME in the provided SDK and toolchain
-find-library NAME                                       display the full path to library NAME in the provided SDK and toolchain
-version                                                 display the version of Xcode; with -sdk will display info about one or all installed SDKs
-enableAddressSanitizer YES|NO                           turn the address sanitizer on or off
-enableThreadSanitizer YES|NO                            turn the thread sanitizer on or off
-enableUndefinedBehaviorSanitizer YES|NO                 turn the undefined behavior sanitizer on or off
-resultBundlePath PATH                                   specifies the directory where a result bundle describing what occurred will be placed
-resultStreamPath PATH                                   specifies the file where a result stream will be written to (the file must already exist)
-resultBundleVersion 3 [default]                         specifies which result bundle version should be used
-clonedSourcePackagesDirPath PATH                        specifies the directory to which remote source packages are fetch or expected to be found
-derivedDataPath PATH                                    specifies the directory where build products and other derived data will go
-archivePath PATH                                        specifies the directory where any created archives will be placed, or the archive that should be exported
-exportArchive                                           specifies that an archive should be exported
-exportNotarizedApp                                      export an archive that has been notarized by Apple
-exportOptionsPlist PATH                                 specifies a path to a plist file that configures archive exporting
-enableCodeCoverage YES|NO                               turn code coverage on or off when testing
-exportPath PATH                                         specifies the destination for the product exported from an archive
-skipUnavailableActions                                  specifies that scheme actions that cannot be performed should be skipped instead of causing a failure
-exportLocalizations                                     exports completed and outstanding project localizations
-importLocalizations                                     imports localizations for a project, assuming any necessary localized resources have been created in Xcode
-localizationPath                                        specifies a path to XLIFF localization files
-exportLanguage                                          specifies multiple optional ISO 639-1 languages included in a localization export
-xcroot                                                  specifies a path to a .xcroot to use for building and/or testing
-xctestrun                                               specifies a path to a test run specification
-testPlan                                                specifies the name of the test plan associated with the scheme to use for testing
-only-testing                                            constrains testing by specifying tests to include, and excluding other tests
-only-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER                            constrains testing by specifying tests to include, and excluding other tests
-skip-testing                                            constrains testing by specifying tests to exclude, but including other tests
-skip-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER                            constrains testing by specifying tests to exclude, but including other tests
-test-timeouts-enabled YES|NO                            enable or disable test timeout behavior
-default-test-execution-time-allowance                   the default execution time an individual test is given to execute, if test timeouts are enabled
-maximum-test-execution-time-allowance                   the maximum execution time an individual test is given to execute, regardless of the test's preferred allowance
-only-test-configuration                                 constrains testing by specifying test configurations to include, and excluding other test configurations
-skip-test-configuration                                 constrains testing by specifying test configurations to exclude, but including other test configurations
-testLanguage                                            constrains testing by specifying ISO 639-1 language in which to run the tests
-testRegion                                              constrains testing by specifying ISO 3166-1 region in which to run the tests
-resolvePackageDependencies                              resolves any Swift package dependencies referenced by the project or workspace
-disableAutomaticPackageResolution                       prevents packages from automatically being resolved to versions other than those recorded in the `Package.resolved` file
-json                                                    output as JSON (note: -json implies -quiet)
-allowProvisioningUpdates                                Allow xcodebuild to communicate with the Apple Developer website. For automatically signed targets, xcodebuild will create and update profiles, app IDs, and certificates. For manually signed targets, xcodebuild will download missing or updated provisioning profiles. Requires a developer account to have been added in Xcode's Accounts preference pane.
-allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration                     Allow xcodebuild to register your destination device on the developer portal if necessary. This flag only takes effect if -allowProvisioningUpdates is also passed.
-showBuildTimingSummary                                  display a report of the timings of all the commands invoked during the build
-create-xcframework                                      create an xcframework from prebuilt libraries; -help for more information.
make: *** [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 64
14:31:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project iValentina (kit: Qt 5.12.1 for iOS Simulator)
When executing step "Make"
14:31:48: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Comment: Hi Rostislav, you mentionned full error code, please provide it in your post as code, it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution was to upgrade Qt from version 1.12 to 1.14.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

/Users/(user_name)/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/devices.py

Change line 53:

```
from :    and "unavailable" not in runtime["availability"] \
to   :    and runtime["isAvailable"] \
```

Change line 80:

```
from :    if "unavailable" not in device["availability"] \
to   :    if device["isAvailable"] \
```

You can also try Qt5.12.8 which will not cause Error 64.

In devices.py, simctl command makes json data of "devices" and "runtimes". And some properties in that json has been changed in Xcode11 CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not solution, but in my case I used this workaround and everything worked ok:

Comment everything in the file:

```
/Your Qt Directory/ mkspecs / features/mac / sdk.mk
```